# Is std::transform SIMD function?

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, simd

Is std::transform SIMD? I mean if I have two arrays
`std::array<int,4> a{1,2,3,4};` and `std::array<int,4> b{1,2,3,4};`. Let's sum this two arrays with `std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),result.begin(),std::plus<>());` and store the result in a new `std::array<int,4> result;` array. Have I done summing with SIMD command? If not how can I achieve SIMD?

Note: I am compiling with clang, with optimization level -O3 and doing release build.

Comment: The only way to know is to compile and check the assembly.  The C++ standard does not require it to create a SIMD instruction.

Comment: That would depend on the compiler, compiler flags, and possibly pragmas

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm updated the question

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not know assembly that much, however this is assembly code generated by godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/KE53cK, please have a look)

Comment: if you really, really want a simd transform, check out https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd

Comment: @Yamahari I've had look at that library, but have not noticed that they have transform functions... , thx anyway, move this as an answer I'll mark it right, but will test it for performance tomorrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not `std::transform` uses SIMD instructions is implementation and compiler dependant.
If you need to be sure that your transform uses SIMD functionality, here's a library that provides a SIMD transform function that has the same interface as the STL one https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd

Comment: `std::transform` is definitely not SIMD because you can pass in any operation you choose.  It's possible that after inlining everything, the compiler might sometimes be able to optimize the resulting code if you pass in an operation that's suitable for SIMD, the same way that a compiler can transform any loop.  The C++ library does include a data type for vectorized operations -- `std::valarray<T>` -- where use of SIMD is still a quality of implementation issue but the operations are chosen to certainly be SIMD-friendly.

Comment: unlikely yes, definitely I wouldn't say, you could specialize for certain calls couldn't you?